# Freeing Up Disk Space /var

Tags: disk-usage

I want to free up some space. When I run ncdu, this is the screen I got:
[image]

`/storage` is another disk, it is not relevant in my question, just ignore it. `/var` directory is too big, and I want to reduce it.
[image]

In `/var/log`, `auth.log.1` takes 6.2 GiB which is so much. Is it required, can I delete it? If not, how can I reduce its size? Also in `/var/log` there is `/journal` directory which is 3.7 GiB. It contains these files in the image below, are there important? How can I reduce their sizes?
[image]

There is also `auth.log` file in `/var/log` which is 660 MiB.

Thanks for all help and info.

Comment: 10GB of logs often means that there is a **problem** that is being logged over and over.  Deleting the logfile is usually a temporary workaround. It's often better to solve the problem, so future logs are normal size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logs are not at all important to you, then yes, you can delete the contents of `/var/log/journal` as well as logs in `/var/log` ending in a number and/or `.gz`.

If you would like to limit the size of the journal directory, edit your `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file and set the `SystemMaxUse` option to a value you can tolerate. For example:

```
SystemMaxUse=250M
```

If you would like to clear out the `/journal` directory to a specific size right now, you can do it like this:

```
sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=250M
```

This will reduce the journal logs to 250M … give or take.

Comment: The `SystemMaxFileSize` option is different, as it controls individual file sizes. `SystemMaxUse` will limit the entire directory to a certain size (more or less). If you do not see it in your config file, add it at the bottom.

Comment: yes I figured it out later, I did not see the ```SystemMaxUse``` I do not know why. I have deleted my comment. Thank you, I have removed the ```#``` and edited the ```SystemMaxUse``` as you tell.